# Are there any defenses for defendant who had a police officer order the filling of their known fraudulent prescription?

Tags: criminal-law, constitutional-law, florida, due-process

Are there any defenses for defendant who had a police officer order the filling of their known fraudulent prescription?

These are the facts:

1. Suspect leaves a voice mail for a fraudulent prescription
2. Pharmacist listens to the order and confirms it is fraudulent with the doctor's office
3. Doctors office notifies police and the police ask the Pharmacist to stall
4. After arrival, the police officer identifies the suspect with the Pharmacist
5. Instead of making the arrest for attempt to obtain a controlled substance by fraud, the police officer orders the pharmacist to fill the fraudulent prescription
6. The pharmacist fills and notifies the suspect that the prescription is ready for pick up
7. The suspect pays for and receives the prescription
8. Immediately upon completion of the transaction, the police officer grabs the prescription and arrests the suspect for two crimes: obtaining a controlled substance by fraud and trafficking.

Comment: I can see several defenses for the police officer and the pharmacist. The suspect is screwed.

Comment: @DaleM, What exactly do you mean by "the suspect is screwed"? The suspected was wronged and can't do anything about it? There has to be some defense for the suspect right?

Comment: @Breakskater There does _not_ have to be any defense for the suspect. Unfortunately, sometimes in life, if you commit a crime, you have to face the consequences. No number of rephrasings of the same question will change that fact.

Comment: "Screwed" in this context means: if the facts above are supported by evidence and there are no other relevant factors, the charge will almost certainly be proved.

Comment: @jimsug, it is wise to explore all the different angles to see where each one leads; a couple have led to dead ends and [one has shown some promise](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5381/can-a-police-officer-authorize-the-sale-of-a-pharmacys-drugs-to-a-suspected-cri). This question was generalized intentionally so people would think outside of the box instead of constraining their thoughts to the question

Comment: I'm not saying that there is _no_ situation where you will have no defense. I am saying that in _this_ situation, unless you introduce new facts, the answer will be the same. But you are _absolutely_ and _completely_ wrong to say that there _has to be some defense for the suspect_. **No one, anywhere, is automatically granted some general defense** - it is up to them to prove it.

Comment: @jimsug, okay, that is your opinion and you're entitled to it. You say there is no defense. What about the rest of the community? Let's open the question to get their thoughts and legal analysis

Comment: @jimsug, to the second topic in your comments, I did not say there has to be some defense for the suspect. The question title clearly says _are there any defenses_. I'm looking for other potential defenses to explore to see where they lead.

Comment: I don't believe this question should be reopened, but you should be able to vote to reopen it. This question has been asked and answered already - it could just as validly have been closed as a duplicate of [this one](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/5529/58), [this one](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/5381/58), [this one](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/5345/58), [this one](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/5289/58), or [this one](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/3643/58). If you are unhappy with the fact that this question is on-hold, please feel free to raise it on [meta].

Comment: And you absolutely **did** say that there has to be some defense for the suspect in your comment, [here](http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5546/are-there-any-defenses-for-defendant-who-had-a-police-officer-order-the-filling?noredirect=1#comment10323_5546).

Comment: @JasonAller, can we clear the comments and resume the question clean for the community to answer?

Comment: @jimsug, can you justify point #5 in the question?

Comment: Your point 5 is answered [here](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/3919/58), [here](http://law.stackexchange.com/q/5381/58) and [here](http://law.stackexchange.com/a/3648/58). You're going to need to go to [meta] now, because you clearly want community input, and they've given it multiple times on your previous questions. Perhaps there you'll get some support for reopening the question.